# Display Items in ComboBox dependent on a Property

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox

I've got a combobox that is bound to a `List<Person>` (ItemsSource is set in CodeBehind).

`<ComboBox Width="120" Background="White" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />`

So the names of all persons are added to the List.

Because it's not necessary to show every name in the ComboBox, I added a property `Hide` of type `bool`. If this property is set to true, the name should not be shown in the combobox.

But how is it possible to add a condition to the Binding of the combobox, so that only those persons are listed who are not supposed to be hidden.

EDIT:
Regarding answers, I added the following code:

```
{
    List<Person> persons;
    ...
    var collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(persons);
    collectionView.Filter = HideFilter;
}

...

private bool HideFilter(object item)
{
   Person p = item as Person;
   return p.Hide;
}
```

But this throws a TargetInvocationException on `collectionView.Filter = HideFilter;`.
What did I misunderstand?

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752348.aspx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could either filter in the code behind, or you could use a item template to bind visibility of the Item to the isHiden property (with a boolean to visilbility converter).  Your XAML code would be:

```
     <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" >
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Visibility="{Binding IsVisible}" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>


public class person
{
    public person(string n, Visibility v)
    {
        Name = n;
        IsVisible = v;
    }
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public Visibility IsVisible { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is a really interesting solution. I've tried it, but it does not work, although the getter runs, and the debugger shows me 'false'. I've to investigate, whats really happens in this case.

Comment: The class has to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise `PropertyChanged` when the `IsVisible` property changes.

Comment: ..and set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the Visibility binding

Comment: @Em1 - _debugger shows me false_.  Don't forget though that whilst your object can return a **bool**, the **Visibility** property is of type _Visibility_ not **bool**.  You may need a **IValueConverter**

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a filter to the CollectionViewSource of the data source, your list,
you can get this collection with the static method CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(list)

you'll get a nice interface where you can add a filter that says (hide = false)

Answer (score 0):

you can apply linq query on the List before making it a source

```
List<Person> persons = new List<Person> ();
var Filter =  from p in persons
           where p.hide == false
           select p;
```

Now renew persons and provide Filter as a list to it cast this Filter into List and defined it combo source...

```
persons  = new List<Person>(Filter);
cbm.ItemSource = persons  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestions is to not do it this way. Why? It is not wrong, **but** it produces empty collapsed rows in the combobox! :/
In my case I had a list of five users and deleted all. But I had still five tiny little clickable(!) rows inside of the combobox. oO

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Visibility="{Binding IsVisible}" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Instead I use code like shown below. It's my solution for a user list. When I mark a user as deleted (if selected, click on button, mark as deleted), it disappears from the list completely.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UserList}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser}"
        DisplayMemberPath="Name"
        IsEnabled="{Binding SelectedUser.HasErrors, TargetNullValue=True, FallbackValue=True, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=False, Converter={StaticResource Bool2BoolNot}}"
        IsEditable="False"
        >
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Deleted}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger.Setters>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Special}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger.Setters>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Super}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkRed"/>
                    </DataTrigger.Setters>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```